# check if an item is selected in menu

Tags: jsf, menu, jstl

I've created a managed bean that reads menu items from XML file and generate the menu with a specified levels in a tree, Now I'm trying to check the current item and make a condition if this item in the menu = "string" then, make this Item as a link and move to another jsp form, here is the code from xhtml file:

popItems is the managed bean

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="#{popItems.outputText == 'SDT'}">
<a href="test.jsp"><h:outputText value="#{node}"/> </a>
</c:when> 
<c:otherwise>
<h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I think the problem in the condition and the comparison between items and the string, can anyone help?!

Comment: What is the error/ issue for you? what is {node}? I suppose its not a managed bean

Comment: No error is generated, just otherwise statement works because when condition is false.
Node is the displayed item from the XML file to the menu.

Comment: So, `#{popItems.outputText}` does not equal `SDT`? Not sure why you think that it's a problem in JSTL. It simply means that `outputText` does not represent the exact value `"SDT"`. That problem is in turn unrelated to `<c:choose>`.

Comment: Yes I know so ,so I'm asking about a way that enables me to compare the current node with the string 'SDT'.